# SQL Server Window Paging Based on # of Groups

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Given the following table structure

| Column |
| --- |
| Id |
| Name |
| DateCreated |

with the following data

| id | Name | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 1/13/2021 |
| 2 | Fred | 1/13/2021 |
| 3 | Bob | 1/12/2021 |
| 4 | Sue | 1/12/2021 |
| 5 | Sally | 1/10/2021 |
| 6 | Alex | 1/9/2021 |

I need SQL that will page over the data based on datecreated. The query should return the top 3 records, and any record which also shares the datecreated of the top 3.

So give the data above, we should get back Joe, Fred and Bob (as the top 3 records) plus Sue since sue has the same date as Bob.

Is there something like ROW_NUMBER that increments for each row where it encounters a different value.

For some context this query is being used to generate an agenda type view, and once we select any date we want to keep all data for that date together.

**EDIT**
I do have a solution but it smells:

```
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) RowNum,CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) DateCreated,Name
                FROM MyTable),
        PAGE AS (SELECT * 
                  FROM CTE
                  WHERE RowNum<=5)

SELECT * 
FROM Page
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE DateCreated=(SELECT MIN(DateCreated) FROM Page)
```

Comment: Hmm the tables show up fine in the preview of edit mode but not here...

Comment: Kind of a combination of `ROW_NUMBER` and `DENSE_RANK`, the latter will change only on distinct changes, but in this case you will get the first 5 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a `TOP 3 WITH TIES` example and a `ROW_NUMBER` example and a CTE to return four records:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dateCreated DATE
)
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
    ( 1, 'Joe', '13 Jan 2021' ),
    ( 2, 'Fred', '13 Jan 2021' ),
    ( 3, 'Bob', '12 Jan 2021' ),
    ( 4, 'Sue', '12 Jan 2021' ),
    ( 5, 'Sally', '10 Jan 2021' ),
    ( 6, 'Alex', '9 Jan 2021' )
GO

-- Gets same result
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES *
FROM #tmp t
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC 


;WITH cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY dateCreated DESC ) rn, *
FROM #tmp
)
SELECT *
FROM #tmp t
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM cte c
    WHERE rn <=3
      AND t.dateCreated = c.dateCreated
)
```

My results:

[image: Results]

Comment: thanks that looks a little cleaner then what I got. Curious to see the execution plan differences

Comment: I've added a `TOP 3 WITH TIES` example which is much simpler code but functionally may not do what you want.  I mean it works for your given sample data but may not bend to more complex examples.

Comment: yea let me see if if WITH ties works with my query which is definitely more complex then my example;-)

Comment: Yea With Ties is the way to do this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As  @Charlieface, we only need to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`. So that the ROW_NUMBER will be tied according to the same value.

When we run the query:

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK ()  OVER(ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) RowNum,CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) DateCreated,Name
                FROM MyTable
```

The result will show as follows:
[image]

So as a result, we can set `RowNum<=3` in the query to get the top 3:

```sql
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) RowNum,CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) DateCreated,Name
                FROM MyTable),
        PAGE AS (SELECT * 
                  FROM CTE
                  WHERE RowNum<=3)

SELECT * 
FROM Page
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE DateCreated=(SELECT MIN(DateCreated) FROM Page)
```

The First one is as yours the second one is as above. The results of the two queries are the same.
[image]

Kindly let us know if you need more infomation.

Comment: This actually returns too much data as your pulling the first 3 groups of DateCreated, we want the first 3 results then any other datecreated which matches that one. WITH TIES is the right answer